# Make bash script to only output(type) without executing

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I am trying to write a bash script that helps users type a command in terminal. However, I want the command to be left un-executed.
This is a quick example:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

function type_for_me() {
  line_number = ( ... do some calculation ...)  # let's say line_number is 25
  if [[ -n $line_number ]]; then
    echo "generates some complex cmd with $line_number"  # I want this line to appear in terminal but un-executed.
  fi
}
```

After running the command I am looking for the following behavior:

```bsh
$ type_for_me
$ generates some complex cmd with 25  # this line waits for user to hit <Enter>
```

Comment: [Here](https://superuser.com/q/1462995/432690).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski What about turning that into an answer, so that this question doesn't stay unanswered forever? (Yes, it's bad that we can't have cross-SE dupes, we have to live with that.)

Comment: Thanks please feel free to move it to an answer.